# Get only ParseObject's children pointers without the include dot notation

Tags: android, parse-platform

When using Parse with Android, I can get a `ParseObject` with its pointers' references without using include. For example, if I have a pointer to an `Author` in a `Book`, when I fetch a book, I can also get the Parse's id of the author in the result.

However, if I'm fetching for a `Shelf` and use `include(books)` to include the books in that shelf, the field containing the author of each book doesn't even come in the resulting list of books. I would need to also use `include(books.author)` to get each author.

I was hoping to avoid doing so when all I need is the Parse id of the author, not all of its contents. Is there any way to get just the child's id of children without using include with the dot notation?

Comment: Can you print the output of the author field when you fetch a shelf? And are you sure you're fetching and not querying? I know iOS and javascript SDKs don't have an include method for fetching, only querying.

Comment: Oh, sorry, meant to say 'querying' in the above. When I query for shelves, I can `include` books but then the reference to the author in the book doesn't come at all. Not even its object id.

Comment: What's wrong with `include("books.author");` ?

Comment: @jeand'arme: My problem with that is the inconsistency of Parse's results. If I query an object without any include, any pointer it contains will come with its class and object id. If I query the same object and `include` one of its Pointers, I would expect that the Pointers of this included pointer would come with their class and object id as well.

I suppose this is not a problem if you are explicitly calling Parse functions. But if you are abstracting it to prevent a coupled architecture, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I only need the object id reference in this case, I solved it by replacing the Pointer column with a String one containing the id it points to.